# Find price with sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I forget my price,

my table is something like this,

i forget my PP column in this table now i want to update this PP column on base on OP and DiscountPercentage.

```
tbl_product

OP       DiscountPercentage   PP
9        10                   0
18       10                   0
180      10                   0
80       20                   0
160      20                   0
```

i want output like this

```
OP       DiscountPercentage   PP
9        10                   10
18       10                   20
180      10                   200
80       20                   100
160      20                   200
```

Comment: How do you determine `PP` based on the two other columns?

Comment: Also, please decide whether you need for MySql, SQL Server, or both.

Comment: PP is my original price, DiscountPercentage is percentage and remaining is my OP   means PP is 200, DisocuntPercentage is 10, Then OP = 200 - (200*10/100 )

Comment: i need answer in Mysql.

Comment: Then delete `sql-server-2008` tag.

Comment: I have two different database, i have to update in both . but my first preference is mysql

Comment: So, you're not asking a MySQL question, you're asking an arithmetic question, right?

Comment: @DMac i m asking sql query with proper logic, if you have no answer than why you do unwanted comment ?? if you have some bit of knowledge than give answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE tbl_product
SET PP = OP / (1 - DiscountPercentage / 100.0) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: I find no consistency in the output of PP based on OP and DiscountPercentage. Therefore my answer will be rather generic. You will need to determine the formula to calculate `PP`.

Use an `UPDATE` query:

```
UPDATE tbl_product
SET PP = <some formula to calculate the value>
```

For example,

```
UPDATE tbl_product
SET PP = (4 * OP) + (42 * DiscountPercentage / 100.0)
```

This will set each row's `PP` value based on the values of the same row's `OP` and `DiscountPercentage` columns.

Comment: The same formula that you used for calculation on your sample output.